# How can setup Email alerts for topbeats (ELK)

Tags: logstash, server-side, elastic-stack

I have setup my ELK stack with topbeat, and I am getting all information of servers like, load, ram usage, disk space usage perfectly.
Now I want to setup alerts for any specific amount of usage if cross like low dis space usage alert on email. How can I achieve the same?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try out Yelp's [ElastAlert](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert) for an OSS solution. 
Elastic have Watcher, and I think Logz.io also offer an alerting mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ElastAlert library, complete sample email alert configuration example  and library setup explained here : http://vaibhavtupe.blogspot.com/2016/07/elasticsearch-jira-alert-and-email.html

Comment: This answer relies almost completely on the content of an external link. Should it ever become invalid, your answer would lose almost all its value. So please [edit] your answer and add at least a summary of what can be found there. Thank you!